# SDL 1.2 for use with C++ on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, c++, sdl

Can I get the [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) libraries on [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian)? I don't actually have a Raspberry Pi, but before I get one I want to know if I can.

If I can then:

- Does it have all the features of SDL 1.2?
- How long does it take to compile code that uses the libraries?
- How fast will the resulting program run?

Comment: Compiling is not super fast, but as long as you keep everything modular it won't be painful.  WRT it working, I don't see why it wouldn't. Qv. http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=48859

Answer (score 2):

I have used SDL 1.2 on the Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, by installing the `libsdl1.2-dev` package that lenik suggests. It also works from the console, so [X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is not needed.

The only special thing with running from the console on the Raspberry Pi, is that you have to check the supported screen size and then initialize your screen with wathever values you get. See [Gordon's post](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-and-sdl/) on this. Another thing to note there is that the Raspberry Pi (at least by default?) uses 16 bit/pixel colors, so use 16 bit/pixel throughout the program for the best performance. Also see the thread *[Idiot's guide to C++/SDL Setup](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=13789)* in the Raspberry Pi forum.

I do roughly this in a platform game I am working on, mostly from the forum thread:

```
SDL_Surface * makeWindow()
{
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK) < 0)
        dieSDL("SDL init failed: %s\n");

    const SDL_VideoInfo* videoInfo = SDL_GetVideoInfo ();
    int systemX = videoInfo->current_w;
    int systemY = videoInfo->current_h;
    int systemZ = videoInfo->vfmt->BitsPerPixel;

    printf ("%d x %d, %d bpp\n", systemX, systemY, systemZ);

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(systemX, systemY, systemZ,
                              SDL_SWSURFACE); // | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
    if (screen == NULL)
        dieSDL("SDL_SetVideoMode failed: %s\n");

    return screen;
}
```

The game is [here](http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.com/p/the-platform-game.html), but there isn't any Raspberry Pi version published yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ apt-cache search sdl
```

gave me (among many others) the following:

```
libsdl1.2-dbg - Simple DirectMedia Layer debug files
libsdl1.2-dev - Simple DirectMedia Layer development files
```

looks like sdl c/c++ development for Raspberry Pi is supported, or at least present in the latest build of Raspbian.

Comment: Have you actually tried using the libraries?

Comment: i have a headless (sans monitor) setup, there's no point. there are plenty of preinstalled games/app that do, however.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a video and posted it on youtube showing how to download and setup SDL 2.0 for the raspberry pi on youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yo7hO7GZ-ug

Comment: 30 minutes video?? are you for real?

Comment: This is clearly someone just trying to promote his Youtube channel...

Comment: @EduardoCosta Self-promotion is not forbidden, preferably including disclosure (which this does) if it involves an appropriate solution to a question (and although the question was not exactly "How do I setup SDL?", the other two prior answers were already more-or-less about that, so to be fair, this one is no more or less appropriate).  I have removed the "please subscribe and share line", however.